# Eclipse gives warnings on inline svg tags/attributes

Tags: html, eclipse, svg

I have the following svg inlined in my html:

```
<div class="navigationItem">                
    <svg class="navigationItemIcon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path d="M257.122,165....">
    </svg>
</div>
```

The svg is displayed and styled correctly, but I get 2 errors in my editor (Eclipse Juno, Java EE perspective)

- On the svg attribute `viewbox=0 0 512 512` I get the error: "undefined attributename".
- On the `<path>` tag i get the error: "undefined tag".

I think I need to import something to tell my editor these are valid normal tags, but I don't know:

- what to import?
- where to import it into (into the html file? into my project as a library? into my eclipse?)
- what is the syntax for importing?

Comment: You can try an SVG Plugin: http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgplugin/

Comment: I do not need a svg viewer or editor in my eclipse, I would like eclipse's html/jsp editor to recgonize svg attributes/tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import svg DTD :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Titre : First SVG</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cercle SVG</h1>

<svg:svg  width="100" height="100">
   <svg:circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg:svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible errors:

1) viewbox is viewBox

2) The path element is not closed i.e. />

Comment: I thought html was case insensitive: <DIV> is the same as <div>. The viewBox actually works fine when viewed, it's just eclipse that doesn't recognize it and I'm wondering why. Also, the path is closed />, it was just a typo when making this question. thanks for noticing, I edited.